# Using in-exact string for xpath identifier

Tags: php, xpath

I am finding I need to locate an almost regexp type string using an xpath query but have not been able to see how to manage it. The current query I am using is:

```
  $result = $xpath->query('//ul/li[starts-with(@id, "message-")]');
```

Which is resulting in some false positives. It should really be looking for message-123 or message-987  etc. Is there a way to tell xpath to use something similar to a \d (digit) in regexps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this XPath 1.0 expression for `'message-' + integer` pattern:

```
//ul/li[
   @id[
      starts-with(., 'message-') 
    and
      number(
         substring-after(., 'message-')
      ) 
    = floor(
         substring-after(., 'message-')
      )
   ] 
]
```

Comment: @Alejandro  thanks that seems to do the trick. I am looking for someone who can help with this project if you are taking new jobs?

Comment: @Jaime Cross: You are welcome. Ask any time. And thanks for the offer, but I'm not taking new proyects right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$xpath->query('//ul/li[matches(@id,"^message-\d{3}")]')
```

Edit: my bad, sorry - try this out:

```
$xpath->query('//ul/li[php:functionString("preg_match", "/^message-\d{3}/", @id)]')
```

Comment: PHP Warning:  DOMXPath::query() [<a href='domxpath.query'>domxpath.query</a>]: xmlXPathCompOpEval: function matches not found on line 19
PHP Warning:  DOMXPath::query() [<a href='domxpath.query'>domxpath.query</a>]: Unregistered function on line 19

Comment: Would that mean my host needs to upgrade php or xpath?

Comment: php versions currently 5.2.16 just asked host to upgrade to 5.3.x ablity to use functionstring is not in 5.2 either  :(